# Iterate through a 3D list by column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file:

`example_table.txt`

`EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeService,EmployeeJob,EmployeeNum
12039,Bob,Morning,Taxi Driver,03489293489
98734,Jacob,Evening,Bus Driver,02084928349
48023,Jenny,Night,Register Attendant,02932389045
23490,Andrew,Morning,Teacher,03941826384
34792,Nautilus,Night,Nurse,02678439985
58023,Ulysses,Evening,Watchman,0983748932`

I made a function that turns this into a 3D list:

```
#NOTE - Take x to be open("example_table.txt","r+")
#NOTE - Take y to be [i.split(",") for i in x.readlines()]
def splitter(lis, char):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(lis[0].split(char))):
        x.append(lis[i].split(char))
    return x
```

If I call `splitter(y,",")`, it gives me the following list:

```
[
['EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeService,EmployeeJob,EmployeeNum'],
['12039,Bob,Morning,Taxi Driver,03489293489'], 
['98734,Jacob,Evening,Bus Driver,02084928349'], 
['48023,Jenny,Night,Register Attendant,02932389045'], 
['23490,Andrew,Morning,Teacher,03941826384'], 
['34792,Nautilus,Night,Nurse,02678439985'], 
['58023,Ulysses,Evening,Watchman,0983748932']
]
```

I would like to iterate through this like so:

```
#Take p = splitter(y,",")
p[0][1 to amount of rows] # as in p[0][2], p[0][3], p[0][4]
p[1][1 to amount of rows] # same as above, only 0 is 1
#Until...                 # et cetera, et cetera
p[4][1 to amount of rows] # Final iteration
```

So,

```
FOR every_row in p:
    FOR every_column in p:
        ITERATE every_row through every_column /*ONCE!!*/
```

I would also like to store these results in a dictionary.

```
v = {
    'EmployeeID':['12309','98734',...,'58023'],
    '...':[...],
    'EmployeeNum':['03489293489',...]
    }
```

I also want this to work with any amount of columns and rows. Any help?

`BUZZYSIN`

Comment: Do you know that the actual data in the inner most list (employee id, etc) is one continuos string and not a list? you would have to call `'string'.split(',')` to split it up, so you could easily access each item, with out having to split a string each time. Also, what is your question specifically?

Comment: Yeah, @Anthony, I knew that. Its in the 2nd code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a simple list comp to split the strings into list with `.split('.')`:

```
>>> l =[
['EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeService,EmployeeJob,EmployeeNum'],
['12039,Bob,Morning,Taxi Driver,03489293489'],
['98734,Jacob,Evening,Bus Driver,02084928349'],
['48023,Jenny,Night,Register Attendant,02932389045'],
['23490,Andrew,Morning,Teacher,03941826384'],
['34792,Nautilus,Night,Nurse,02678439985'],
['58023,Ulysses,Evening,Watchman,0983748932']
]
>>> l = [x[0].split(',') for x in l]
>>> l
[['EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName', 'EmployeeService', 'EmployeeJob', 'EmployeeNum'], ['12039', 'Bob', 'Morning', 'Taxi Driver', '03489293489'], ['98734', 'Jacob', 'Evening', 'Bus Driver', '02084928349'], ['48023', 'Jenny', 'Night', 'Register Attendant', '02932389045'], ['23490', 'Andrew', 'Morning', 'Teacher', '03941826384'], ['34792', 'Nautilus', 'Night', 'Nurse', '02678439985'], ['58023', 'Ulysses', 'Evening', 'Watchman', '0983748932']]
```

you can then re-organize your list to better suit what you want:

```
>>> keys = l[0]
>>> keys
['EmployeeID', 'EmployeeName', 'EmployeeService', 'EmployeeJob', 'EmployeeNum']
>>> values = [[] for _ in range(len(keys))]
>>> for li in l[1:]: #exclude the keys
    for index,item in enumerate(li):
        values[index].append(item)
>>> values
[['12039', '98734', '48023', '23490', '34792', '58023'], ['Bob', 'Jacob', 'Jenny', 'Andrew', 'Nautilus', 'Ulysses'], ['Morning', 'Evening', 'Night', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Evening'], ['Taxi Driver', 'Bus Driver', 'Register Attendant', 'Teacher', 'Nurse', 'Watchman'], ['03489293489', '02084928349', '02932389045', '03941826384', '02678439985', '0983748932']]
```

and with these, its an easy dict comp:

```
>>> d = {key:val for key,val in zip(keys,values)}
>>> d
{'EmployeeNum': ['03489293489', '02084928349', '02932389045', '03941826384', '02678439985', '0983748932'], 'EmployeeID': ['12039', '98734', '48023', '23490', '34792', '58023'], 'EmployeeService': ['Morning', 'Evening', 'Night', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Evening'], 'EmployeeJob': ['Taxi Driver', 'Bus Driver', 'Register Attendant', 'Teacher', 'Nurse', 'Watchman'], 'EmployeeName': ['Bob', 'Jacob', 'Jenny', 'Andrew', 'Nautilus', 'Ulysses']}
```

Comment: best answer ever. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to make a dictionary from your file:

```
with open('example_table.txt') as employee_file:
    headers, *rows = [r.rstrip('\n').split(',') for r in employee_file]
employees = dict(zip(headers, zip(*rows)))
```

The `headers, *rows = something` is a Python 3-ism that is short for `headers, rows = something[0], something[1:]`.

The `zip(*rows)` will take a 2-by-2 list (a list of lists) and transpose it.

So if `rows` is:

```
[['12039', 'Bob', 'Morning', 'Taxi Driver', '03489293489'],
 ['98734', 'Jacob', 'Evening', 'Bus Driver', '02084928349'],
 ['48023', 'Jenny', 'Night', 'Register Attendant', '02932389045'],
 ['23490', 'Andrew', 'Morning', 'Teacher', '03941826384'],
 ['34792', 'Nautilus', 'Night', 'Nurse', '02678439985'],
 ['58023', 'Ulysses', 'Evening', 'Watchman', '0983748932']]
```

Then `list(zip(*rows))` would return:

```
[('12039', '98734', '48023', '23490', '34792', '58023'),
 ('Bob', 'Jacob', 'Jenny', 'Andrew', 'Nautilus', 'Ulysses'),
 ('Morning', 'Evening', 'Night', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Evening'),
 ('Taxi Driver', 'Bus Driver', 'Register Attendant', 'Teacher', 'Nurse', 'Watchman'),
 ('03489293489', '02084928349', '02932389045', '03941826384', '02678439985', '0983748932')]
```

The `dict` constructor will accept a sequence of key-value pairs and make a dictionary out of them, so zipping headers to corresponding value lists (or tuples in this case actually) will create our dictionary:

```
{'EmployeeJob': ('Taxi Driver', 'Bus Driver', 'Register Attendant', 'Teacher', 'Nurse', 'Watchman'),
 'EmployeeService': ('Morning', 'Evening', 'Night', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Evening'),
 'EmployeeNum': ('03489293489', '02084928349', '02932389045', '03941826384', '02678439985', '0983748932'),
 'EmployeeName': ('Bob', 'Jacob', 'Jenny', 'Andrew', 'Nautilus', 'Ulysses'),
 'EmployeeID': ('12039', '98734', '48023', '23490', '34792', '58023')}
```

If you need the values to be lists instead of tuples, you can use `map` on the last line to convert each tuple to a list:

```
employees = dict(zip(headers, map(list, zip(*rows))))
```

So the final result would look like this:

```
>>> with open('example_table.txt') as employee_file:
...     headers, *rows = [r.rstrip('\n').split(',') for r in employee_file]
...
>>> employees = dict(zip(headers, map(list, zip(*rows))))
>>> employees
{'EmployeeJob': ['Taxi Driver', 'Bus Driver', 'Register Attendant', 'Teacher', 'Nurse', 'Watchman'], 'EmployeeNum': ['03489293489', '02084928349', '02932389045', '03941826384', '02678439985', '0983748932'], 'EmployeeID': ['12039', '98734', '48023', '23490', '34792', '58023'], 'EmployeeName': ['Bob', 'Jacob', 'Jenny', 'Andrew', 'Nautilus', 'Ulysses'], 'EmployeeService': ['Morning', 'Evening', 'Night', 'Morning', 'Night', 'Evening']}
```

Comment: sorry, @TreyHunner, I didn't want tuples.

Comment: @BUZZYSIN I added an update to the bottom showing how you can change the last line to convert the tuples to lists.